# Can you hurt Stink Eyes in Bastion?

Tags: bastion

[Stink Eyes](http://bastion.wikia.com/wiki/Stinkeye) (closed eye creatures) creatures are mostly unharmed when firing at them, if their eye is closed.

Can you harm them at all in this state, or are they totally immune?

Comment: FYI: Those creatures are called "stink eyes".

Comment: @Shaun - forgot the name when I posted. I'll edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, you just need a weapon to penetrate that tough armor.

The **Fire Bellows** will eat right through that if I'm not mistaken.  This was my go-to weapon for every occasion.  The **Galleon Mortar** is just as effective with its longer range.

Otherwise you'll need an upgraded weapon that can ignore armor to do that.  Such as the **Army Carbine** with **Razor Rounds**, the **Cael Hammer** with **Checkered Face** or **Dueling Pistols** with **Armor Eater Rounds**.

With these weapons, you can give a lot of hurtin' to those **Stink Eyes** whether they have their eyes closed or not.

Comment: I can confirm that the Mortar also does armor damage.

Comment: I kept trying to read this in the Narrator's voice.

Comment: @Merus: Haha I never looked at it that way.  It definitely sounds like something he'd say.  :)

Comment: The poison upgrade for the breaker bow also seems to affect them.

Answer (score 2):

Slight thread necromancy but I've got more info:

I can damage them with my (unpenetrating) Fang Repeater although it does 1 damage regular and 1 damage on crits. So they can be taken down without armor penetration but it takes time.

Comment: The same is true for any weapon that can deal any kind of damage.